# My jQuery doesn't seem to be working with Wijmo Grid

Tags: jquery, wijmo

I built a smart data grid full of cells that will identify (on blur) whether or not they were changed, and if the value went up or down.

Here's what it looks like. The grey tooltip appears when the user hovers a box that has been changed and tells them what the value was when the page first loaded.

---

[image]

---

I'd like to convert this to a Wijmo Grid, but keep the same up/down scripts to show when and how values are changed. However, when I initialize the table as a Wijmo grid, suddenly my scripts stop working **in all browsers**.

**Question:** Why does this happen and is there an easy fix? Can you not access Wijmo cells with traditional jQuery and Javascript?

**Partial HTML Code ([Full code and working example without Widjmo here](http://jsfiddle.net/Fgdec/12/)):**

```
<table id="data-grid">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>March</th>
            <th>April</th>
            <th>May</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" value="12000" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="1000" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="100000" /></td>
        </tr>
```

**Here is my current jQuery code ([Full code and working example without Widjmo here](http://jsfiddle.net/Fgdec/12/)):**

```
$(function() {
    // Initializes data grid as a Widjmo Grid (currently commented out)
    //$("#data-grid").wijgrid();

    // Array to store the initial values in grid
    var initialValues = [];

    // Assigns an index ID to each cell in the grid
    $('input').each(function(index) {
        initialValues[index] = $(this).val();
        $(this).data('id', index);
    });

    // Checks cell(s) for changes on blur (lose focus)
    $("input").blur(function() {
        var $t = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
        var $s = parseInt(initialValues[$(this).data('id')], 10);

        // Value has changed
        if($t != $s) {
            var sign = "";
            if($t-$s > 0) {
                sign="+";
            }
            $(this).parent().children(".tooltip").remove();
            $(this).parent().append("<div class='tooltip'>Initial " + $s + "<br/>Change " + sign + ($t-$s) + "</div>");
        }

        // Value is no different from intial value
        if($t == $s) {
            $(this).removeClass("up down");
            $(this).parent().children(".tooltip").remove();
            $(this).parent().children(".up-indicator, .down-indicator").remove();
        }

        // Value is greater than initial
        else if($t > $s) {
            $(this).removeClass("up down");
            $(this).parent().children(".up-indicator, .down-indicator").remove();
            $(this).addClass("up");
            $(this).parent().append("<div class='up-indicator'></div>");
        }

        // Value is less than initial
        else if($t < $s) {
            $(this).removeClass("up down");
            $(this).parent().children(".up-indicator, .down-indicator").remove();
            $(this).addClass("down");
            $(this).parent().append("<div class='down-indicator'></div>");
        }

        // Conpute the net change
        netChange(initialValues);
    });

    // Displays tooltip of changed items
    $("input").hover(function() {
        $(this).parent().children(".tooltip").toggle();
    });

    // Computes the net change in the data grid
    function netChange(initialValues) {
        var runningTotal = 0;
        $('input').each(function() {
           runningTotal += parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
        });

        var intialTotal = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < initialValues.length; i++) {
            intialTotal += parseInt(initialValues[i], 10);
        }

        var changes = $(".up, .down").length;

        $("#items").text(changes + " Items");
        $("#net").text("Net: " + (runningTotal - intialTotal));
    }
});
```

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome Version 25.0 [.1364.152]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Wijmo plugin code uses `$.browser.msie` in their code which is **deprecated** in jQuery 1.3 and completely removed in jQuery 1.9. See jQuery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/ and below was the comment in **bold** on why it was removed.

> We recommend against using this property; please try to use feature detection instead (see jQuery.support). jQuery.browser may be moved to a plugin in a future release of jQuery.

---

Your tooltip code work once after I chose the earlier version of `jQuery 1.8` in the fiddle.

**Fixed fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/Fgdec/13/

---

In your fiddle you had selected jQuery 1.9 which did not had the `$.browser.msie`, so It was throwing the below error in chrome console.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined jquery.wijmo-open.all.2.3.8.min.js:31
(anonymous function) jquery.wijmo-open.all.2.3.8.min.js:31
(anonymous function) jquery.wijmo-open.all.2.3.8.min.js:61
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined jquery.wijmo-complete.all.2.3.8.min.js:34
(anonymous function) jquery.wijmo-complete.all.2.3.8.min.js:34
(anonymous function) jquery.wijmo-complete.all.2.3.8.min.js:34
```

Comment: The code that I posted is working -- I have commented out the Wijmo initialization. If you un-comment line 3 in the jQuery to initialize the Wijmo grid, you'll see that the jQuery becomes unresponsive. This is the issue I'm having.

Comment: I take that back. Apparently jQuery 1.9.x was the issue after all. Thanks for the catch!